# GPU Memory leak in HTML5 canvas

Tags: google-chrome, memory-leaks, html5-canvas, webgl, gpu

I am trying to add a webgl canvas to a normal canvas using

`ctx.drawImage(webglcanvas, 0, 0, webglcanvas.width, webglcanvas.height);`

And what I see is there is a memory leak in Chrome task(Shift+Esc) manager.

I was previously suspecting a library(fabric.js) but now after a lot of debugging found that if we add a webgl canvas to 2d canvas ,there is a definite leak in GPU memory.

You can find more about this [here](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/4140)
The link will redirect a issue of fabric.js but if I use a normal 2d canvas instead of fabric.js , I still face the same issue.

Is this a issue in the browser itself?

**EDIT-1**
@Blindman67 , @gman , I created 2 more fiddles for clarity , if you go to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/tzxozx4b/15/) , you can find leak clearly. And if you go to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/tzxozx4b/14/), there is absolutely no leak bcoz am not adding to 2d canvas.  Try uploading few images of different dimensions and observe chrome task manager for memory changes in both the cases.

In first case, bcoz I am adding to a 2D canvas there is leak.

Whereas in the latter case there is 0KB leak , if you click clear memory and observe task manager you can see that the GPU memory will come back to the point where it started.

Hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: Can not see a leak, ran sample http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/tzxozx4b/11/ from the link you gave on chrome beta, and Canary, gave it a good workout, peaks at 0.5Gig and then is stable. *I use webGL and 2D canvas together all the time. The process window's GPU memory counters will not show a memory leak. Leaking memory is unrecoverable and requires a page reload, all else is just deferred garbage waiting for a good time to be cleaned up. When using webGL (expectation of performance) GC will lower its priority.  A memory leak will cause a crash, no crash no leak.

Comment: I don't see a [leak either](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/9tur2r13/)

Comment: I edited the question, pls check after EDIT-1

Comment: @gman and Blindman67 , did anyone of you got a chance to look at the updated fiddles? I am sure you can see some leaks definitely

Comment: As i also wrote on the fabricjs issue tracker, @subhfyu546754 is using a gl context lost simulator describing it as a disposer of resources. I think this is a wrong base to build a thesis upon.

Comment: @subhfyu546754 your new link is no different. There is no leak. Change you load function to set a timeout to reload the image again after the onload fires, say every 100 ms. If there was a memory leak then it would run out of memory very soon and crash. This does not happen, it just keeps running. What you see as a leak is just GC being slow, it wont clean up untill there is a need.

Comment: If I set a timeout , then it runs fine as the canvas width/height doesn't change. In my application I get images of different width/height ,so I need to delete and create new canvas for it because otherwise I won't be able to maintain aspect ratio. Also, our testers say that this issue only persists in chrome as of now but Edge and FF are running fine.

Comment: Please indicate which operating system you are running. it might make a difference.

Comment: am testing in windows 7/8/10